# Removing the hyphen from an Event with an undefined title (Fullcalendar)

Tags: javascript, html, css, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-5

It seems as default, if there is no Title defined in the Event Object, then Fullcalendar will add a hyphen after the date range using the pseudo `::after` class. (See photo). I do not want this hyphen, if there is no Title defined.

This is the only way I know how to remove the hyphen from an Event title.  **Is there a better way?**

add this to CSS:

```
.fc-event-time.no-after:after {
  content: none !important;
}
```

add this line to `eventDidMount`:

```
$(arg.el).find('.fc-event-time').addClass('no-after');
```

here is a full example of `eventDidMount`:

```
        eventDidMount: function (arg) {
            // console.log($(arg.el))

            html = '<div class="mx-1">' +
                '<i id="addSlot" class="fas fa-chevron-up"></i>' +
                '<span class="badge badge-pill badge-primary">' + arg.event.extendedProps.MaxSignups + '</span>' +
                '<i id="minSlot" class="fas fa-chevron-down"></i>' +
                '</div>' +
                '<div class="mx-1">' +
                '<i id="delSlot" class="fas fa-trash-alt"></i>' +
                '</div>';
            $(arg.el).find('.fc-event-time').addClass('no-after');
            $(arg.el).find('.fc-event-title').addClass('d-flex justify-content-end').append(html);

        },
```

event object sample:

```
[
    {
        "Duration": 30,
        "MaxSignups": "6",
        "color": "blue",
        "editable": true,
        "end": "2020-09-11 15:00:00",
        "id": "20200911_11",
        "start": "2020-09-11 14:30:00"
    }
]
```

[image: default hyphens]
[image: with no-after css]

Comment: define "better". What do you feel is wrong with your current approach? Otherwise we don't really know what you're aiming for.

Comment: P.S. I can't actually reproduce your issue: https://codepen.io/ADyson82/pen/RwaGOpe using fullCalendar 5.2. No hyphen is added, and I haven't customised the code or CSS in any way. Maybe this is actually happening due to something else _you've_ done?

Comment: I pasted my event object into your example, and got the hyphen.  What is wrong with my event object? (I'll include the event object in my question)

Comment: I will also note that if you resize the event, the hyphen will disappear. I'm using version 5.0.0.

Comment: From playing about with it a bit, it only seems to occur on events with certain lengths / timings, but I'm not quite sure of the exact pattern yet. I think it might be when either the event's duration is equal to or less than the slot duration, and/or the start/end times aren't at the slot boundaries (e.g. starting at 10 past the hour instead of on the hour). It doesn't entirely make sense to me. So, it seems like maybe a bug - you can report bugs to the fullCalendar project - see https://fullcalendar.io/reporting-bugs

Comment: Thank you for your time!